# Is this seam normal for Quartz counter top

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops, quartz

I was wondering if this installation looks normal (see pictures). One of the reasons that we have asked for the quartz countertop was that we thought that the seam wouldn't be that obvious. But the thing that we have got looks very obvious to us. So I was wondering if my expectations was unrealistically high or this is actually an unprofessional work. Also, it seems that the part underneath is not sealed properly (please see the last pic). I was wondering if this is normal practice. The first picture is the seam, the second is the view from the side, and the last one is the view from under.

[image: The seam]

[image: side view]
[image: Underneath]

Comment: It looks like the cuts were not as good as they could have been, nor does the sealing look like it was done very well. However seams are an obvious requirement of quartz or granite that needs to be cut and joined somewhere. For this reason I avoid the material where a single piece will not achieve the result - as no matter who says what - seams will be visible or become visible as the work settles over time. Your seams however seem a bit more excessive for new installation - where you purchased the quartz what do the show room pieces look like ? Seam or no seam ??

Comment: Did you get a reference before hiring this guy? Next what's the contract say? The top of the counter looked good on my phone other than the color, the front thickness , well this is a natural / stone product some variation in thickness is normal. The under side seam is totally normal. So is this professional? could be. Was the guy a hack? Not totally.  This is a craft, there are different levels of craftsmen from how the ×%* has he survived? to the master that makes works of art.

Comment: Part of what makes the seam so visible is irregularities along the edges.  You may be able to polish some of that out to make it less blatant, but the seam will still be visible.

Comment: References and seeing prior work are a good thing before you choose a contractor. One obvious aspect here is not using a proper colored epoxy, which is one of the ways that stone joints are made far less obvious - mixing the epoxy to closely match the stone color. Many manufacturers have a specific color-matched epoxy system to be used on their countertops. The other obvious thing is not finishing the joints - the joint area should be polished after gluing, The glue left smeared over the face of the joint in the second picture is very amateurish, as is the unfilled bottom of the joint.